# Phrase written as a propositional statment and written as such symbolically.

Tags: logic

The phrase: “There is no statistic that is either a record or cannot be broken”.

Written symbolically as a propositional function and given a domain of discourse.

Okay so I've given this a try: Let the Domain of discourse be "all statistics".  Let P(x) = "x is a record" and Let Q(x) = "x can be broken"

My best guess: ∀x, P(x) $\vee$ $\neg$ Q(x)

The more i think about this thing the more confused I get, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the domain of discourse to be everything, or at least all abstract things, and explicitly symbolize "$x$ is a statistic" with $S(x)$.

The statement you're trying to render symbolically is a negation: "there is no $x$ such that ...", so be sure you understand what is being negated. The statement asserts that there is no $x$ such that $x$ is a statistic and such that either $P(x)$ or $\neg Q(x)$. That is,
$$
\neg \exists x\, (S(x)\land (P(x)\lor \neg Q(x))).\tag{1}
$$
This can be written in a few equivalent forms. Recall, or notice, that $\neg\exists\equiv \forall\neg$, and that $\neg(A\land B)\equiv (A\to\neg B)$. So (1) is equivalent to all of the following:
$$\begin{align}
\text{(1)} &\equiv \forall x\, \neg(S(x)\land (P(x)\lor \neg Q(x))) \tag{2} \\
&\equiv \forall x\, (S(x)\to \neg(P(x)\lor \neg Q(x))) \tag{3} \\
&\equiv \forall x\, (S(x)\to (\neg P(x)\land  Q(x))) \tag{4} \\
\end{align}$$
The last equivalence is by De Morgan. (4) can be rendered into English as "Every statistic isn't a record and can be broken."

---

If you *do* take the domain of discourse to be "all statistics", then you can drop the $S(x)$ clauses and simplify. (1) becomes
$$
\neg \exists x\, (P(x)\lor \neg Q(x)),\tag{1'}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\forall x\, (\neg P(x)\land  Q(x)). \tag{4'} \\
$$

Comment: So for your solution are we still implying that P(x) and Q(x) are unchanged?

Comment: "Interchanged" how? They still mean what you defined then to mean, so, No.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is likely from the confusion over the use of the phrase "Either this or that". There are two interpretations of the phrase "is either a record or cannot be broken":

```
 "Either this or that" as "This or that"

 "Either this or that" as "This or that, but not both this and that"
```

The latter interpretation is called "exclusive-or". Your "best guess" is right if the intended interpretation of "Either this or that" is NOT "exclusive-or" i.e. your best guess is right if the phrase "Either this or that" means "This or that".